# Compiling .dll into the executable

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible an application that references multiple libraries to compile only into a .exe file and not .exe + all the .dlls?

I know I can rename all the namespaces to match that of the application, but I don't want to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use the tool called [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630) by Microsoft. After you build your projects it will let you combine all of the dll's in to one exe.

Here is a [CodeProject Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9364/Merging-NET-assemblies-using-ILMerge) showing you how to use it

```
ilmerge /target:winexe /out:SelfContainedProgram.exe 
        Program.exe ClassLibrary1.dll ClassLibrary2.dll
```

UPDATE: as [Blindy mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10112218/80274) If your code uses anything in the [`Reflection` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/136wx94f.aspx) you may run in to problems after you merge the files. It is a place to start looking if you start getting errors while running your program after you have merged.

Comment: Ehh most of the reflection API will work fine as long as it works on in-memory objects (which the merged libraries will be in). It's just trying to hard-load external assemblies from the same folder that will crash with a file not found exception.

Comment: @Blindy true, that is why I say "may" instead of "will". And listing the whole namespace is a lot easier than naming every single class in it that can touch a external assembly.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, that's exactly what [ilmerge.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630) is meant to do.

Careful of late bound libraries though (ie `Assembly.LoadFrom`).